# Values of <td></td> is not returned using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html-parsing, htmlunit

I am having a table structure in a web page as below

In this i am trying to get all the values in the tr using the HtmlUnit code as below.

```
<tr  class="odd" id="rawmeta-123">
       <td class="rowid">1</td>
       <td>Arun</td>
       <td class="date">2006-04-13</td>
       <td></td>
       <td class="date"></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
```

List byXPath = page2.getByXPath("//tr[@class='odd']/td/text()");

It returns the first three and fifth td values. But the values for the for the other are not returned.(

```
<td></td>). How to get this value as null using HtmlUnit?
```

I highly appreciate your comments.

Comment: Please can anyone respond to this question?
I am stuk up in this...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this : ?

```
HtmlTableRow tr = (HtmlTableRow) page.getByXPath("//tr[@class='odd']/");
for (HtmlTableCell td: tr.getCells() ) {
    if (td.getTextContent().isEmpty()) {
    // this is null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But this doesn't work. The problem is the above getbyxpath is not parsing the tag <td></td> itself.